# How to get extension of file from URL which is stored in Cloud FireStore firebase

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I have a url which is stored in cloud database firestore.I want to check the extension of file whether it is an image or a video.Since it does not have any extension after a .DOT i can not do any substring method on this type https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abc-43546.appspot.com/o/content%2Fc86608030813072?alt=media&token=6505c905-cbc2-40e9-a48d-7edda3090666

Please help i did not find any working solution from the internet.Thanks

Comment: I suggest you write extra information, in addition to the download URL, about the file into the database that you'll need later.  Don't depend on just that URL itself.  So, if you need that file type later, write that to the database as well.

Comment: Yeah i did this because none of the solution worked.

Comment: @HassanTariq might you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you can do it in `Android`, `Java` I guess?

In `JavaScript` (`TypeScript` version here) it works like below. Here's part of my `nodemailer` function sending an email with an attachment.

```
import { DocumentSnapshot } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore';
import { EventContext } from 'firebase-functions';

async function onCreateSendEmail(
  snap: DocumentSnapshot,
  _context: EventContext
) {
  try {
    const contactFormData = snap.data();
    ...
    const mailOptions = {
      attachments: [
        {
          contentType: `${contactFormData!.contentType}`,
          filename: `${contactFormData!.fileName}`,
          path: `${contactFormData!.fileUploader}`,
        },
      ],
    ...
    }
  ...
  }
...
}
```

The `contentType`, `fileName` and `fileUploader` are defined on the frontend side. In that case, these are defined right before the form is submitted and take the data from the form object. The `fileUploader` is essential, that's the form control name in which all the file's metadata is stored.